# How to test class::method() which creates a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, file, python-unittest

I am trying to implement a class which has a method for creating new file based on keyboard input. 
I have a file named *FileManipulator.py* which contains class + method:

```
class FileManipulator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fileChecker(self):
        print("+++ EXECUTING FILE CREATION METHOD +++")
        new_custom_filename = input("Give filename: ")
        custom_file_path = input("Give path where to create file: ")
        print(custom_file_path)
        try:
            new_file = open(custom_file_path + "/" + new_custom_filename + ".ttcn3", "x+")
        except OSError:
            print("Creation of the file %s failed" % new_custom_filename)
        else:
            print("Successfully created the file %s" % new_custom_filename)
```

Executing in this way:

```
fm_obj = FileManipulator()
result = fm_obj.fileChecker()
```

I can see the *"file_name_give_as_input.ttcn3"* created on the path that I also give as an input.

> Problem is that result will have type NONE

In this case I cannot properly test my method. 
I've create python unittest like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from FileManipulator import FileManipulator
import os

class FileManipulatorTest(TestCase):
    def test_fileChecker(self):
       FM = FileManipulator()
       result = FM.fileChecker()
       self.assertEqual(os.path.abspath(result, "ut_testing.ttcn3"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

And test fails becasue:

> Expected :None
>
> Actual   : .\test_cases\ut\ut_testing.ttcn3

My question is: 
**How I can create unittest which will test if "file.ttcn3" is "physically" created at a specific location?**

Maybe I am testing wrong, as I start the method which will wait for user input and this breaks the automation of this particular test and could drive to - test hang on execution.

Comment: Normally you would mock the function that creates the file (`open` in your case) but that obviously won't create the file physically on disk. That you can check via `os.path.exists`.

Comment: If you can't unittest it then your design is wrong. In the above case, your first issue is that you're mixing UI layer (getting inputs from user) with domain layer (creating files etc). Split those responsabilities and you'll already have something better. Also, you don't want to print() but let errors propagate and leave it to the calling to handle them (here again that's UI layer responsability, not domain layer. Then you'll just have to mock filesystem access (here the builtin `open`) to test it's called as expected (you can safely assume that builtin functions work as expected).